# What slang words are used in social networks with the meaning of "cool"?

Tags: vocabulary, slang

What English slang can be used in social networks to say that something is great and you like it?

Comment: "*That phone is **dope**?*"

Answer (score 1):

Some synonyms I've come across:

- Awesome
- Mind Blowing
- Mind==Blown
- Uber
- Hot
- Shit (really!)